# Oracle Data Integrator Oracle to Excel encoding

Tags: excel, oracle, encoding, character-encoding, oracle-data-integrator

I try to export my Oracle view data to Excel sheet using Oracle Data Integrator.
English text is exported good, but russian (cyrillic) is wrong!
Help me please, how can I configure datasources and encoding.
After export to excel data has cp1252 encoding, but there is no place where such encoding is configured!

Information:
Oracle DS use jdbc:oracle:thin and

```
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
```

(in windows registry and environment variables(same to database).
ODI starting with product.conf:

```
AddVMOption -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
AddVMOption -Dsun.jnu.encoding=Cp1251
AddVMOption -Duser.language=ru
AddVMOption -Duser.country=RU
```

(and I see such values in Help-About-Properties.

Excel DS use jdbc:odbc and

```
charSet=cp1251
```

property.
Oracle 12c, ODI 12c.

If I execute simple java code with

```
-Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
```

option - russian language displays correct, but not over ODI...

I would be glad any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my own question.
May be it is obviously for anyone, but I found solution not fast...

I need to change Windows property **Current language for non-unicode programs**. from English to Russian.

So I even not need "AddVMOption -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251" options in ODI - they are set correct after changing property.

Hope this information to be helpful for someone.
[image: Properties]